# How to set filter in cuda-memcheck (or compute-sanitizer)

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, cuda-gdb

I am developing a fairly big project (have around 1200 kernels so far). I have 1 kernel that possibly has some memory race which is why it's giving different answers every time. I want to find it by performing cuda-memcheck on that specific kernel. So naturally, I am trying to use `--filter` option in `cuda-memcheck` with `--tool racecheck` option. The codebase is big and performing cuda-memcheck on all kernels especially with racecheck enabled will take an eternity.

The official [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#specifying-filters) says using key value pair as: `{key1=val1}[{,key2=val2}]`.

I am not really sure what exactly this means and whatever I have tried resulted in invalid options message. I could not find any example online as well as Nvidia cuda-samples provided with the toolkit.

So far, I have tried these (and probably all combinations of these):

`cuda-memcheck --filter <kernel_name>,kns <Executable>`

`cuda-memcheck --filter key1=<kernel_name>, key2=kns <Executable>`

`cuda-memcheck --filter key1='<kernel_name>', key2='kns' <Executable>`

`cuda-memcheck --filter <kernel_name>,[kns] <Executable>`

I am not sure exactly how to interpret the documentation. An example would be great. Thanks.

Note: I can use cuda-memcheck with other options and my executable is compiled correctly with flags like `Xcompiler, lineinfo` etc.

Comment: Note that `cuda-memcheck` is [deprecated](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#about-cuda-memcheck) in favor of `compute-sanitizer` since CUDA 11.5. `compute-sanitizer` supports GPUs starting with the Maxwell architecture (compute capability 5.0), i.e. if you work on an older Kepler GPU, you can't use the newer tool. `compute-sanitizer` is part of the CUDA toolkit since version 11.0, I think.

Comment: `compute-sanitizer` also has the `--filter` option with the same syntax, but it is deprecated in favor of the `--kernel-regex` option which is probably easier to use.

Comment: My interpretation of the syntax according to the documentation is `cuda-memcheck --filter kns=<kernel_name_substring> <Executable>`. Note that the kernel name is [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: @paleonix Thanks, I have changed the title to include both for future references.

Your interpretation is correct and it worked for me, thanks!
I will add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @paleonix in the comments the correct format is:

`cuda-memcheck --filter kns=<kernel_name_substring> <Executable>`
or

`cuda-memcheck --filter kne=<kernel_name> <Executable>`

The key difference between these two options is: (According to [Nvidia-documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#specifying-filters))

`kns:` User specifies the complete mangled kernel name.

`kne:` User specifies a substring in the mangled kernel name.

Note: starting cuda 11.0 the `cuda-memcheck` tool is deprecated and replaced with `compute-sanitizer` it works as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: You should accept your answer to mark the question as solved.